# self join a table to give record without null

Tags: sql, oracle

I was experimenting on different approach to achieve the below output .

```
CON_ID    Compartment    AMOUNT       EXP_DT
train     Compartment 1     100     '20-jan-2016'
```

Please Find the Data used below .

```
with src_t as 
(
select 'A' as miot_id,'Train' as Obj_id from dual
union
select 'B' as miot_id,'Candy' as obj_id from dual
),
eat as (
select 'Candy' as eat_id,'Compartment1' as compartment,'20-jan-2016' as exp_dt from dual
union
select 'Cookies' as eat_id,'Compartment2' as compartment,'20-feb-2016' as exp_dt from dual
),
miot_t as (
select 'A' as miot_id,'Compartment1' as vin from dual
UNION
select 'B' as miot_id,'Compartment2' as vin from dual
),
condition_t as (
select 'Train' as con_id,100 as amount from  dual
)
```

I tried the below query.

```
Select  con_id,Compartment,amount
      , exp_dt
From    src_t
Left Join condition_t
        On condition_t.con_id = src_t.obj_id
Left Join eat
        On eat.eat_id = src_t.obj_id
Left Join miot_t
        On miot_t.miot_id = src_t.miot_id;
```

but it is showing null value as .

```
CON_ID    Compartment    AMOUNT       EXP_DT
  null    Compartment 1     null     '20-jan-2016' 
 Train      null            100         null
```

I have tried using Max function . that is one way to do it .but is there any other way to it ..like self join etc..so that it wont affect the performance . Thanks for the answer

which means Compartment 1 in the train have candy for 100 rs that expire on '20-jan-2016'

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling I am doing someone's homework for them, but here it is. A left join means always include the table values from the table on the left (first mentioned), even when there are no matching values from the table on the right. NULL will be substituted for the missing right table values.

In your case, you are only interested in matching values, you have no interest in non-matching values, so you want to do an inner join, not an outer join ('left join' is short hand for 'left outer join'). A good practice is to always work from the container table inward to the contained tables. This makes your SQL easier to understand. Here is the SQL where I got your desired result set:

```
WITH src_t
     AS (SELECT 'A' AS miot_id, 'Train' AS obj_id
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'B' AS miot_id, 'Candy' AS obj_id
           FROM DUAL)
   , eat
     AS (SELECT 'Candy' AS eat_id, 'Compartment1' AS compartment, '20-jan-2016' AS exp_dt
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'Cookies' AS eat_id, 'Compartment2' AS compartment, '20-feb-2016' AS exp_dt
           FROM DUAL)
   , miot_t
     AS (SELECT 'A' AS miot_id, 'Compartment1' AS vin
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'B' AS miot_id, 'Compartment2' AS vin
           FROM DUAL)
   , condition_t
     AS (SELECT 'Train' AS con_id, 100 AS amount
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT con_id
     , compartment
     , amount
     , exp_dt
  FROM condition_t
       INNER JOIN src_t ON con_id = obj_id
       INNER JOIN miot_t ON src_t.miot_id = miot_t.miot_id
       INNER JOIN eat ON eat.compartment = miot_t.vin;
```